# CFFORM data not readable in IE9

Tags: forms, internet-explorer, coldfusion

I have form, which I use for users to login to the site. It works in Chrome, but for some reason not in IE 9.
Here is the form:

```
<cfform name="loginform" action="login.cfm" method="post">
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span2">
        User Name:
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <cfinput type="text" name="username" required="yes">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span2">
        Password:
    </div>
    <div class="span2">
        <cfinput type="password" name="password" required="yes">
    </div>
</div>
<div class="span12">
    <div class="span2">
        <cfinput name="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="login" type="submit">
    </div>
</div>
</cfform>
```

I am normally accessing the variable as **#form.username#**, but it is empty if being used in IE.

The simplified use here:

```
<cfif isdefined("FORM.submit")>
   username: #form.username#
</cfif>
```

Comment: When I do CFDUMP for #form, field username is [empty string]. Everything else is there. Why? When I rename the field, it doesn't make any difference. If I rename it and move after the password field, it is still empty.

Comment: When I change username type to password, it works. It for some reason ignores type="text" fields.

Comment: Unless you have a need to use cftextarea, or any other client side 'form' feature, don't use cfform. For such a simple form as this, there really is no need.

Comment: Nothing to do with the question, but if you don't include a message attribute on your cfinput tags, the required="yes" won't work properly.  This is one of the nice things with cfform, if you use it properly.

Comment: *if you don't include a message attribute on your cfinput tags, the required="yes" won't work properly*  The "message" attribute is optional. If you omit it, CF still validates the field, but displays a boiler plate error message instead.

Answer (score 1):

I can't see anything wrong with your code above when I run it I have the username field available to me in the form scope correctly.  What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

To better debug this I would suggest the following:

- Look at the source of the first page and see if there is anything
  strange there.
- Install Fiddler2 (http://www.fiddler2.com/) then use this to see
  exactly what is being posted to login.cfm.

Other things to look at:
Are you using a javascript or CF framework that might be interfering with things?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything overtly wrong with your code either. Did you try this in Firefox as well? Sometimes you can get better debugging information there. Possibly an actual error message with it. Both IE and Chrome can do a bit too "good" of a job of obscuring errors on the page.

My suggestion would also be to use plain form tags. Don't use cfform tags. There's not much need for them here. They aren't really helping you much. You could do your own validation on those fields and know exactly what it is that you are validating. You could also test your field that way. Simply change that cfinput to an input and see if that field becomes available in your post. That would pretty quickly let you know that there's an issue with your implementation of the CFFORM tags.

And it's getting a little OT, don't forget to trim the input and wrap it in XMLFormat() and add cfqueryparams to your SQL lookups to minimize scripting and injection attacks. You can also use CF's scriptProtect or rewriting URLs in IIS to help. Allowing free-form entry to FORMs or URLs without any validation is VERY dangerous.